# Installing Tweepy using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, tweepy

I tried installing Tweepy for python using homebrew by the command `brew install tweepy` 
 But it showed the following error: 
 
`Error: No available formula with the name "tweepy" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`  
 What command should I use? 
Please don't suggest to use pip, I already tried that many times, couldn't succeed. 
Edit: 
Using `pip install tweepy` , results in following: 
`ADITIs-MacBook-Air:~ aditinarware$ pip install tweepy`
`Collecting tweepy`
  `Downloading tweepy-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
`Collecting six>=1.7.3 (from tweepy)`
  `Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
`Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 (from tweepy)`
 `Downloading requests_oauthlib-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
`Collecting requests>=2.4.3 (from tweepy)`
  `Downloading requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (576kB)`
`100% |████████████████████████████████| 583kB 129kB/s`
`Collecting oauthlib>=0.6.2 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)`
`Downloading oauthlib-2.0.1.tar.gz (122kB)`
`100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 117kB/s`
`Installing collected packages: six, oauthlib, requests, requests-oauthlib, tweepy`
  `Found existing installation: six 1.4.1`
`DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.` 
    `Uninstalling six-1.4.1:`
`Exception:`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main`
    `status = self.run(options, args)`
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run`
`prefix=options.prefix_path,`
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install`
`requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)`
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall`
`paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)`
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove`
`renames(path, new_path)`
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames`
`shutil.move(old, new)`
`File`
 `"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move`
`copy2(src, real_dst)`
`File`
 `"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2`
`copystat(src, dst)`
`File`
 `"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat`
`os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)`
`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:` `'/var/folders/_0/qcvk5fqn7yl39jf9g7c1bdh40000gn/T/pip-N2V_my-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'`

`

Comment: How do you use pip? What command did you execute? What the version of python?

Comment: python version: 2.7.10

Comment: command executed: `pip install tweepy`

Comment: @equal_I2 Please check the edit

Comment: Will you try with `--ignore-installed`? (from http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210021/217570)

Comment: I tried `sudo easy_install-2.7 tweepy`. It's finally installed :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Homebrew doesn't provide packages for python generally.

I have to say you should use pip.